# How to assign current system time to a String^ variable?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, c++-cli, visual-c++-2013

How can I get the current system time at a button click event and assign it to a `String^` variable in a (possibly) specified format (like:YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS)?

I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: String^ s = DateTime::Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss");

Comment: @HansPassant Thank your very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f4c8f33.aspx) function together with [localtime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf12f0hc.aspx) function.

Example code:

```
//#include <time.h>
time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;
time(&rawtime);
timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
//The years are since 1900 according the documentation, so add 1900 to the actual year result.
printf("Date: %d/%d/%d Time: %d:%d:%d",timeinfo->tm_year + 1900, timeinfo->tm_mon, timeinfo->tm_mday, timeinfo->tm_hour, timeinfo->tm_min, timeinfo->tm_sec);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it, however @HansPassant's one liner seems like a more appropriate solution here.

Comment: No problem, I haven't noticed you're using C++/CLI :)